# NDsolve and Coupled first order ODE solving

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, syntax

I am new to this community and also to *Mathematica*. I am trying to solve a set of coupled first order differential equations related to the shape of a liquid drop. The code is as follows :

```
file = OpenWrite["profile.dat", FormatType -> OutputForm]
a = 0.29; b = 136250000; zmin = 2.022; smax = 7.330;
Eq1 = r'[s] == cos[θ[s]]
Eq2 = z'[s] == sin[θ[s]]
Eq3 = θ'[s] == (2*a) - (b*z[s]) - (sin[θ[s]]/r[s])
sol = NDSolve[{Eq1, Eq2, Eq3, r[0] == 0,z[0] == zmin, θ[0] == 0}, {r, z, θ}, {s, 0, smax}]
Write[file, r[s], " ", z[s]]
Close[file]
```

However, while I am evaluating the code I am getting two errors constantly as mentioned below;

1)

> Power::infy: "Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.

2)

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at s == 0;

Kindly help me to resolve this. Also, I am unable to plot or write the value of `r[x]` and `z[x]` for each value of `s`.

Comment: For starters, The cosine and sine functions in mma are `Cos` and `Sin`.

Comment: You have a singularity boundary condition with r[0]=0 which is what is being flagged via the error: `ndnum`.  Why not try using `NDSolveValue` and [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) to export data.  Your code does run with these short modifications and setting `r[0]=0.0000001` instead of `0`.  But then I run into `MaxSteps` issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Cos[]` and  `Sin[]` and excluded the singularity in numerical calculations.

```
a = 0.29; b = 136250000; zmin = 2.022; smax = 2.99; s0 = 0.;
Eq = {r'[s] == Cos[θ[s]], 
   z'[s] == Sin[θ[s]], θ'[s] == 
    2*a - b*z[s] - (Sin[θ[s]]/r[s])};
ic = {r[s0] == 10^-7, z[s0] == zmin, θ[s0] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[{Eq, ic}, {r, z, θ}, {s, s0, smax}];
{Plot[Evaluate[r[s] /. sol], {s, s0, smax}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"s", "r"}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[z[s] /. sol], {s, s0, smax}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"s", "z"}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[θ[s] /. sol], {s, s0, smax}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"s", "θ"}]}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: I think it would be useful to OP, who mentions their inexperience, if you could comment on what was wrong with their code and what you changed to make it work.

Comment: there is nothing to comment on, just obvious errors with the use of functions `Cos[], Sin[]` and one singularity, which should be excluded in numerical calculations.

Comment: Hello Alex and MarcoB, thanks a lot. I was stuck with this errors since last two days. It helped me a lot. Can you kindly tell me how I will be able to store the values of r,z, and theta for each value of s in a single .dat file?

Comment: @Mr.X Please see my comment in your original question about `Export`.